# What is the logic behind the thinking that electron must take a complicated path through the two slits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment

Electrons moved in lumps, but unlike bullets, there was interference at the backstop. How?

> How can such an interference come about? Perhaps we should say: "Well, that means, presumably that it is **not true** that the lumps either through hole 1 or 2, beacuse if they did, the probabilities should add. **Perhaps they go in a more complicated way.**. . . "Well, perhaps **some of them go through 1, and then they go around through 2, and then around a few more times, or by some other complicated path . . .then by closing hole 2, we changed the chance that an electron that started out through hole 1 would finally get to the backstop . . ."**. . .$^\text{1}$

I couldn't conceive the bold text really. What did it say? Going first through 1, the electron closed the hole 2? Is it so? Yes, I do know, the double-slit experiment can't be explained in this way; but even so, how did this idea(ie. the bold text) that the electron takes complicated path come to exist? So, can anyone help me to understand what this text is saying?

$^\text{1}$ **Lectures on Physics 3** by Feynman, Leighton, Sands.

Comment: Well, it's just a *guess* - it *could* happen that way. I don't think there's anything deeper to understand here - the author just invented something that *could happen* to show how explaining new phenomena works - you guess until you get it right.

Comment: Turn the question around. Why, are you allowed to consider path with a kink at one of the slits, but not paths with kinks elsewhere? Why paths with one kink, but not two. Feynman is alluding to path-integrals, and this formalism doesn't put limits on the nature of the variations that are allowed.

Comment: @ACuriousMind: Sir, I really do want to know what the bold text means. Knowing,although, that it's a guess, how can I go forward without understanding the vain guesses & attempts? So, can you help me explain what complicated path means??

Answer (score 1):

If a lump is supposed to react to the state of a hole, then the lump must know about the state of the hole. If the lump has no ability to see its surroundings, then the only way for the lump to make sure that it could go through a hole is to actually go through the hole.

assumption that electron has no sight + observation that electron seems to know about its environment -> idea that electron moves all around the environment.